# Should everything be a BIP?

Tags: bip

Once LukeDashJr said (or implied) on Twitter that all Bitcoin ideas, standard candidates and proposals and even stuff tangentially related should be BIPs. He even voiced that the Lightning spec should be made in form of BIPs instead of [BOLTs](https://github.com/lightning/bolts). In fact there is even a BIP for [a proposed Bitcoin unit denomination](https://bips.xyz/176).

And yet there are many Bitcoin ideas and even full protocol standards that get standardized out of the BIPs repository. Some examples:

- Lightning BOLTs
- Lightning bLIPs
- Ark
- DLCs
- Utreexo
- Statechains
- Spacechains
- Softchains
- LNURL
- "value4value" podcasting
- and other things I forgot or sillier and smaller things

It feels like most members of the Bitcoin community don't really think of the BIPs as the place for such things and prefer to reserve them for bigger ideas or proposals for soft-fork changes to the core Bitcoin protocol.

So what is the actual answer? Should these things have been BIPs or not?